# Как скрыть footer, если человек печатает в input?

Tags: html, css

Проблема заключается в том, что когда человек заходит в какой-либо из input(ов), footer перекрывает его. Вопрос, как, и можно ли вообще скрыть что-либо, при условии, если человек печатает?

[image: Сайт]

[image: Подвал перекрывает input]

Comment: input.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  //тут пишите что вам нужно сделать, пока человек печатает
});

Comment: нужно было адекватно всё сверстать, и не делать футер фиксированным

Comment: Знаю, это просто как временное решение, где-нибудь в другом месте пригодиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример касаемо вашего вопроса

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
inputs.forEach(inp =>{

inp.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  content.style.display = 'none';
});

inp.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
  content.style.display = 'block';
});

})
```

```css
.content{
  margin: 50px;
  padding : 50px;
  color: red;
  background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 
  <input type="text" placeholder="text">
  <input type="password" placeholder="password">
</form>
<div class = 'content'>Hide when typing</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение моей проблемы!

Comment: А как использовать querySelector для нескольких элементов? Мне нужно ещё передать input[type="password"] .

Comment: 'querySelector' берет первое совпадение. Вам может помочь querySelectorAll('input') , вернет Dom элементы, потом циклом навешайте на них listener

Comment: переделал пример

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!